# Unable to parse a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, typescript, silex

My api sends back a JSON response like this using PHP Silex:

```
{"response":true,"message":"Bla","userId":"AAA"}
```

But i can't parse it in my Typescript frontend

```
this.authService.login(body).then((result : any)  => {
    console.log(result.data); // => {"response":true,"message":"Bla","userId":"AAA"}         
    let parsed = JSON.parse(result.data);
    console.log(parsed.message); // => throws  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0\n at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

My php endpoint using PHP and Silex Framework:

```
$app->post('/user/login', function (Request $request) use ($app, $config) {
    $email = $request->request->get('user-email');
    $password = $request->request->get('user-password');
    $rsp = loginUser($email,$password);
    return $app->json($rsp);
});
```

When try and hardcode the json object into code, it does parse!

**UPDATE SOLUTION** 
I had to use trim() for result.data to remove whitespaces, somehome the response came with whitespaces and JSON didn't like that. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Its probably a whitespace use trim()

Comment: `console.log(typeof result.data);` ?

Comment: @DieterKräutl but whitespace is allowed between JSON tokens

Comment: I think there is something funky going on on pos1. What do you get if you echo the json string?

Comment: It seems as though the data is already parsed.

Comment: what does `console.log(result.data.message)` show?

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af3rcwx0/2/) showing that JSON parsing works for the JSON as described. `// => {"response":true,"message":"Bla","userId":"AAA"}`

Comment: @Pointy the type of result.data is string

Comment: @Exterminator before parsing result.data, result.data.message gives null after parsing it throws an error

Comment: @AndyJ it does parse when i hardcode the JSON string, but it doesn't when i want to parse the response from the server

Comment: @Yassine can you show us the actual result you are getting `console.log(result)` without hardcoded value

Comment: @DieterKräutl it works. Thank you so much, i used result.data.trim() and it worked

Comment: Good nose for that kind of stuff... I ran into something similar a while back. Took me very long to figure it out.

Comment: @DieterKräutl thank you man, i tried EVERYTHING, for 3 DAYS.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION**

i used result.data.trim() for it to work, somehow the response had whitespaces and JSON didn't like that.

Comment: It would actually be better for you to make sure the output is clean from the *server* (the API out), than to employ an end-result cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a `\u0000` char somewhere coming from your PHP code.

Try to remove these characters from your JSON string as soon as you get it from PHP:

```
this.authService.login(body).then((result : any)  => {
    string = result.data.replace("\u0000", "");
    string = string.replace("\\u0000", "");
    let parsed = JSON.parse(string);
```

Comment: Why the double replace? Based on the OP's console output, they clearly don't have the literal string `\u0000` in their data. An actual null character (or some other invisible control character) is quite plausible, however.